# Is there a way to join strings in a special way in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Eg:
I have a list

```
temp = ["TOM", "JOHN"]
```

I want to join such that the result is

```
" Hi! TOM Welcome. Hi! JOHN Welcome."
```

Something whose pseudocode would be like this

```
"Hi! {} Welcome.".join(temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. A combination of a generator expression (or a list comprehension) and a `" ".join` to join the formatted texts.

```
>>> names = ["TOM", "JOHN"]
>>> " ".join(f"Hi! {name} welcome." for name in names)
'Hi! TOM welcome. Hi! JOHN welcome.'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for string formatting, here is one using f-strings:

```
l = ["TOM", "JOHN"]
' '.join(f'Hi {i}! Welcome.' for i in l)
```

output:

```
'Hi TOM! Welcome. Hi JOHN! Welcome.'
```

Here is another, using `format`:

```
l = ["TOM", "JOHN"]
' '.join('Hi {0}! Welcome.'.format(i) for i in l)
```

And finally, the good old `%` substitution:

```
l = ["TOM", "JOHN"]
' '.join('Hi %s! Welcome.' % i for i in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a so called f-string. In addition to that I used a function that lets you change the message easily:

```
temp = ["TOM", "JOHN"]

def message(name):
    return f"Hi! {name} Welcome."

out = " ".join(message(i) for i in temp)
print(out)
```